# What is the "class-noun" for online and offline?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

If something can either be yellow or red, green, blue, then its "redness" or "yellowness" "class-noun" would be its COLOR.

If something can either be fast or slow, then its "fastness" or "slowness" "class-noun" would be its SPEED (or VELOCITY).

What would be the "class-noun" for something that could be "online" or "offline", to describe its "online-ness" or "offline-ness"?

---

EDIT:

Clarification:

I am talking more about something that takes place as part of an ongoing process, or otherwise after the process has finished. Nothing is connected in my case, and the internet is not involved.

Comment: Perhaps its _connectivity_ (or _connection status_)? Not particularly elegant…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I guess that would work, but I didn't make myself clear. I am talking more about something that takes place as part of an ongoing process, or otherwise after the process has finished. Nothing is connected in my case.

Comment: How about its **availability**?

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think that really works in my case... If some process can take place during some other process, or only after that other process is done, I wouldn't call it "available" or "unavailable"... But now that you got me talking about it... maybe "concurrency" would be more suitable? The problem I see with "concurrency" is that it suggest something happens in parallel, while in my case something happens "as part of".

Comment: Well, your question is far from clear. Can the **color** be another color while it is red, or only when it is not-red?

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess I could be clearer, but this sort of thing requires some rubber duck that speaks back :) Anyway, the color can only either be red or not red, yellow or not yellow. nothing in between.

Comment: I think I require additional clarification. Is this "online" and "offline" closer to "on the record" and "off the record" than it is to "connected" and "disconnected"? I'm thinking of the terms "offline discussion" meaning "a discussion happening after a meeting has adjourned"

Answer (score 1):

If the number of alternatives can be quantified, then the generic term is [state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/State). Look in the section of the article under science and technology.